# How to save data when going from page to page in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have split a page into multiple screens and can't figure out how to bind the data from each screen so you don't lose what the user has inputted if you go back a screen then come back again.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23489159/pass-custom-objects-to-next-activity-in-xamarin-android/37361586#37361586

Answer (score 2):

Use SettingsPlugin (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin)

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Plugin.Settings;
using Plugin.Settings.Abstractions;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class PropertyStorage
    {
        private const string KeyMyPropertyX = "myPropertyX";

        public static string MyPropertyX
        {
            get { return AppSettings.GetValueOrDefault(nameof(MyPropertyX), string.Empty, KeyMyPropertyX); }
            set { AppSettings.AddOrUpdateValue(nameof(MyPropertyX), value, KeyMyPropertyX); }
        }

        private static ISettings AppSettings
        {
            get { return CrossSettings.Current; }
        }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
PropertyStorage.MyPropertyX = "abc";
```

or get value: `PropertyStorage.MyPropertyX`